# Why are "help" and "assist" not directly interchangeable in a sentence where the context would remain the same?

Tags: word-usage, grammaticality, verbs

I was writing a sentence with the word "help" and wanted to substitute it for the word "assist" but realized I could not do that without restructuring the sentence.

My original sentence, "I'll **help you overcome** the obstacle" (sentence 1), sounds fine.

But swapping out the word "help" led to: "I'll **assist you overcome** the obstacle" (sentence 2) which does not sound right.

I feel like it should be: "I'll assist you **with overcoming** the obstacle" (sentence 3), but I cannot figure out why the direct substitution (sentence 2) is incorrect when the two sentences have the exact same meaning and both "help" and "assist" are verbs? Is sentence 1 actually incorrect?

Additionally, I suppose the original sentence could also have been written as "I'll help you **to overcome** the obstacle," which would lead to the substitution of "I'll assist you **to overcome** the obstacle"; this doesn't sound as bad as sentence two but still doesn't seem quite right?

Why can't I directly interchange these words?

Comment: Just because one word can mean the same thing as another word does not mean that it takes the same syntactical form.

Comment: I realize this is not necessarily very assistful ;-), but it's because the verb *help* allows two objects: a person being helped, and an action that you are helping with; while *assist* only allows one object (the person being helped).

Comment: @ Hellion That should be an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Per both the [American Heritage](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=assist) and [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/assist) dictionaries, *assist* is typically used to mean more of a supplementary effort, while *help* is more of a direct action, with AH defining it as "to give assistance to; make it easier for..." and MW as "to give assistance or support to."

The difference is pretty subtle, but it helps explain why *assist* is usually followed by something like *with...* or *in...* . If someone offers to *help* me get a job, I would expect more effort on their part than if they offered to *assist* me in getting a job.

There's also a certain formality in both "help you to" and "assist you with." You can avoid that by just saying *help*, but because *assisting* is providing supplementary effort, in most cases you'll have to keep the *with* or *in* specifier to indicate what you're doing.

To your original sentences, the first one, "I'll *help* you overcome the obstacle," is an (unconditional) offer that you'll do what you can to help that fellow.

If you tell a fellow "I'll *assist* you with overcoming that obstacle," you're implying that that fellow must do their part in overcoming the obstacle, and you'll supplement *their* effort where you can.

Imagine you're on the side of a busy highway with a blown tire in the rain, and two folks stop to help. Person A offers "I'll help you change that tire," and Person B offers "I'll assist you with changing that tire." Person A's offer is a lot more direct, while Person B sounds strangely formal for the situation at hand.